# Launch EC2 instance that doesn't appear in the AMI list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to launch an instance of `g4dn.4xlarge` but I don't find such an instance in the list when I click on Launch Instance (under Instances).

**Update:**

I'm in region us-west-2 (Oregon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **instance type** is only available in certain regions at the moment. This **is not** an AMI.

From the [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-available-ec2-instances-g4-with-nvidia-t4-tensor-core-gpus/) it is available in the following regions

> You can launch G4 instances today in the US East (N. Virginia), US East (Ohio), US West (Oregon), US West (N. California), Europe (Frankfurt), Europe (Ireland), Europe (London), Asia Pacific (Seoul), and Asia Pacific (Tokyo) Regions, in Amazon SageMaker, and (as of October 1, 2019) Amazon EKS clusters.

Comment: I'm in region us-west-2 (Oregon)!

Comment: Not only that, but it is also only available in certain AZs of each region (in my experience)

Comment: Using EKS or sagemaker @Alon?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams no, just EC2->Instances->Launch Instance

Comment: Which AMI are you trying to use?

Comment: This is for EKS and Sagemaker according to documentation @Alon

Comment: @adamkgray I'm looking for an AMI of g4dn.4xlarge but there no such a thing in the list

Comment: @ChrisWilliams could you add a link to the docs that mention that, please?

Comment: Heres the link to the docs: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-available-ec2-instances-g4-with-nvidia-t4-tensor-core-gpus/

Comment: Just to be clear this is also not an AMI @Alon, this is an instance type

Comment: I didn't say it's an AMI. I said it doesn't appear in the AMI list when I click Launch Instance, so I though there mighr be a way to create maybe a custom AMI and choose the instance type you want.